# Add list view item to listview control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to fill a list view from a datatable but when I run the code I recieve a weird error that I can't figure out.

The code:

```
        DataTable allTracks = tracks.getByMedia();

        for (int i = 0; i < allTracks.Rows.Count; i++) {
            DataRow r = allTracks.Rows[i];

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = r["track_number"].ToString();
            lvi.SubItems.Add(r["track_name"].ToString());

            lvTracks.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

Error :

```
  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The program thinks that the lvi variable is not set or null, but when I go into Debug mode, I can see that lvi is definitly initialized and set and is containing the

```
right text + sub item . :S
```

Also if I put this instead of the

```
lvTracks.Items.Add(lvi);
 Messagebox.Show(lvi.Text)
```

It shows the correct value, and does not trigger the error....

Comment: while you are debugging the code exactly at which line of code you got this error?

Comment: not sure if this is it, but you may want to try a foreach loop - foreach (DataRow r in allTracks.Rows). This will save some potential room for error.

Comment: I found the error, it seems that lvTracks was not yet initialized :( dooo! Code is working now ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing apparently wrong with the listviewitem; I suspect that the error is that one of your field names in the data row is incorrect.

Comment: I checked that but all the field names are correct and no field is empty or null. When I replace the add with this line : MessageBox.Show(r["track_number"].ToString() + " " + r["track_name"].ToString()); it shows the correct number + name

Answer (score 0):

It seems the one of the fields contain a null value as converting null values to String Throws error.

I dont think Listviewitem is null in any case beacuase it gets intantiated every time in loop

try

```
DataTable allTracks = tracks.getByMedia();

    foreach(DataRow r in allTracks.Rows) {

        string track_number= r["track_number"]!=System.DBNull.Value?r["track_number"].ToString():"";
        string track_name=r["track_name"]!=System.DBNull.Value?r["track_name"].ToString():"";
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = track_number;
        lvi.SubItems.Add(track_name);
        if(lvTracks!=null)
        {
        lvTracks.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
```

Please note that there exists two different null 
One for .Net CLR this is 'null' and the other for Database that is 'Syatem.DBNull.Value'

Comment: I tried this but it throwed in the same error it did before, I am thinking that their might be something mis with the lvTracks list view...

Comment: have you checked that your Listview 'lvTracks' is not null? bcoz adding anything to a null object will throw an error.This may be wierd but it may happen if your Listview is dynamic. try writing the code inside if(lvtrack!=null)

Comment: Yes that was the error (a), the lvTracks was created dynamic by an function that I had forgotten to call